# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}(\{2x\}-1)(\{3x\}-1)dx$, where {x} is fractional part of x.

Tags: integration

I've tried expanding the expression, but then I get the term $\{2x\}\{3x\}$ which seems to be quite hard to Integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{ 2x\} -1= \begin{cases}
x-1 & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
x-2 & \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}$

$
\{3x\} - 1= \begin{cases}
x-1 & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3} \\
x-2 & \frac{1}{3} < x \leq \frac 23 \\
x-3 & \frac 23 < x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$

So now you can split it:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\frac 13} (x-1)^2 dx + \int_{\frac 13}^{\frac 12} (x-2)(x-1) dx + \int_{\frac 12}^{\frac 23} (x-2)^2dx + \int_{\frac 23}^1 (x-3)(x-2)dx $$

Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that 
$$\{ 2x\}\equiv \begin{cases}2x & \forall x\in[0,1/2) \\ 2x-1 & \forall x\in[1/2,1).\end{cases}$$
Now do the same for $\{3x\}$ and split up your integral accordingly.

Then all these expression become trivial to evaluate

Comment: I got it! Thanks....